# jquery dynamic content and date output

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

```
var jsonObj = jQuery.parseJSON(passData);
thisId = jsonObj.id;
thisPage = jsonObj.page;
thisPageItem = jsonObj.item;
if (jsonObj.json != undefined) {
    $.each(jsonObj.json, function (key, tempJson) {
        if (tempJson.position != undefined) {
            var tempId = tempJson.id;
            var tempStyle = tempJson.position;
            objJsonArr[tempId] = tempStyle;
        }
    });
}
for (var i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
    var tempList = window.objJsonArr;
    var tempDom = '#dropAbleArea #area.' + i;
    $(tempDom).css('top', dropObjectPositionArr[i].top);
    $(tempDom).css('left', dropObjectPositionArr[i].left);
    console.log("Out " + objJsonArr[i]);
    $(tempDom).load('images/pageThree/' + i + '.svg', null, function (e) {
        console.log("In " + objJsonArr[i]);
    });
}

$.each(objJsonArr, function (key, value) {
    if (value != undefined) {
        $('#dropAbleArea div#area').on('', function (e) {
            $('#dropAbleArea div#area.' + key + ' g#ball path#bk').attr('style', value);
        });
    };
});
```

the return is

```
[Log] Out fill:rgb(244, 133, 142) (3.html, line 130)
[Log] Out fill:rgb(130, 202, 156) (3.html, line 130)
[Log] Out fill:rgb(207, 229, 174) (3.html, line 130)
[Log] Out fill:rgb(130, 202, 156) (3.html, line 130)
[Log] Out undefined (3.html, line 130, x4)
[Log] In undefined (3.html, line 132, x8)
```

Q1: I can't get the javascript array data in the `console.log("In " + objJsonArr[i]);`

Q2: How can i get the dynamic content in the

```
$('#dropAbleArea div#area').on('',function(e){
    $('#dropAbleArea div#area.' + key +' g#ball path#bk').attr('style',value);
});
```

Comment: Where objJsonArr is defined? You should have a var objJsonArr = .... somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The `complete` function given to [`jQuery .load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) captures the variables `objJsonArr` and `i`. But when the function is executed, the loop has already finished and `i` has the value `9` and `objJsonArr[9]` seems to be undefined.

You can see the same effect with a delayed function

```js
var a = [ 1, 2, 3 ];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('a[' + i + ']=' + a[i]);
    }, 500);
}
```

which gives the output

```
a[3]=undefined
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DGr5V/)

You can "fix" this with creating an additional scope by wrapping the anonymous function, where you capture the loop variable's value in a another variable `k`

```js
var a = [ 1, 2, 3 ];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    setTimeout((function(k, v) {
        return function() {
            console.log('a[' + k + ']=' + v);
        };
    })(i, a[i]), 500);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DGr5V/1/)

In your case, this would be something like

```js
$(tempDom).load('images/pageThree/' + i + '.svg', null, (function(v) {
    return function (e) {
        console.log("In " + v);
    };
})(objJsonArr[i]));
```

*Update:*

I just learned about [`jQuery.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/#jQuery-proxy-function-context-additionalArguments) and it seems to be the solution to your problem. Taking my first example and applying `jQuery.proxy` to it will give

```js
var a = [ 1, 2, 3 ];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    setTimeout($.proxy(function(k, v) {
        console.log('a[' + k + ']=' + v);
    }, null, i, a[i]), 500);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DGr5V/3/)

This is equivalent to the closure in my second example, where the two values are captured. Equally, using `$.proxy` in your program will be

```js
$(tempDom).load('images/pageThree/' + i + '.svg', null, $.proxy(function (v, e) {
    console.log("In " + v);
}, null, objJsonArr[i]));
```